# Android - doing background work every few minutes

Tags: android, android-service

I need to write some application which will be do some background work for every few minutes. My question is how I can start this work from service. Do I need make this using Threads and calculating time using some System utils or maybe there is better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Handler` and `postDelayed` method:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    public void run() {
       // your work
    }
}, minutes * 60 * 1000);
```

If the interval is sufficiently long you can also consider using `AlarmManager`.

Answer (score 1):

(cant seem to add comment, so adding as an answer)

since this task will be performed continuosly, i'd extend Xion's example like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
  public void run() {
     // your work
     //...
     handler.postDelayed(this, minutes * 60 * 1000); //this will schedule the task again
  }
}, minutes * 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to make by using threads. You can simply do this by AlarmManager.
For the reference see this link it will helps you.
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService.html

Comment: by using handler your service run only for one time.by using alarm manager your service works continously.